# Storing arrays in localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm building an app with Appery.io.  It's basically a search app that returns results and then you can click into the results to see details.

Results are returned from a REST api in JSON format, and each results has a number of different items in it, including one that is a JSON array which contains multiple sets of three name/value pairs.

I need the array associated with each result to be available in the details page for that result.  I don't want to simply run the search again in the details page, because it is a relatively lengthy process and would slow down the entire app.

I'm aware of using `JSON.stringify()` to make the array a string, and then storing each array in local storage.  However, when I do that in Appery.io,  it seems that I either a) just save the first result of the array, or b) am doing it wrong.

Can any provide any insight into how I can go about doing this?  Happy to provide code, clarify my question, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a JSON string that you want to store on client side to retrieve later on say, another page?

Comment: Show some code to see how are you doing it, so we can say is it's wrong or what.

Comment: I may be wrong but why don't you try storing it in window.name property. Here is a good link for that http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-session/

Comment: localStorage is essentially an Object, a key: value store. It can even be written to as `localStorage[key] = value; `.  So in some sense it can only ever keep the previous value, if the code keeps using the same key.  In order to store multiple values, the key must be varied.  localStorage doesn't care about whether the string value represents JSON or something else, but there is a size limit. localStorage also doesn't care if the value string is LZ compressed.  See http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If there's some problem using `JSON.stringify()` with Appery.io, try the approach storing them as comma-separated string (unless you're having commas in values):

```
> ["foo", "bar"].join();
>> "foo,bar"
```

And them returning them:

```
> "foo,bar".split(",");
>> ["foo, "bar"]
```

Of course, if you're having commas in values, you can use explicitly specified separator for values, like:

```
> ["foo,bar", "foz,baz"].join("#");
>> "foo,bar#foz,baz"
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` works well with standard objects, arrays, strings, numbers.  Dates, not so much, it converts them to a string and parse does not reconstruct them with `Date()`.  Custom objects, `JSON.stringify()` may look for a `.toJSON()` or `.toString()` on a custom object but `JSON.parse()` doesn't reconstruct.